# How to convert icon to png with alpha transparency in delphi?

Tags: delphi

The code below will extract icon from file and convert it to png but without alpha transparency ?

```
var
   IconIndex : word;
   icon:TIcon;
   png:TPngImage;
   bmp:TBitmap;
begin
  IconIndex := 0;
  icon := TIcon.Create;
  icon.Handle := ExtractAssociatedIcon(hInstance,pChar(Edit1.Text), IconIndex) ;
  bmp:= TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.LoadFromFile('blank.bmp');
  DrawIcon(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, icon.Handle) ;
  png := TPngImage.Create();
  png.Assign(bmp);
  png.SaveToFile('icon.png');
end;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [PngComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127) contain a unit PngFunctions.pas, where you can have a look at

`procedure ConvertToPNG(Source: TGraphic; out Dest: TPngImage);`

There you can find the code to convert a TIcon into a TPngImage - or just use that procedure.

Comment: Hi Uwe! I try to convert a 256x256 sized icon with ConvertToPNG() and I get a "out of system resources" / "Systemressourcen erschöpft". Any clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: @Stefan, can you file a reproducable test case at https://bitbucket.org/uweraabe/pngcomponents, please?

Comment: Issue#6 created with testcase attached.

Comment: @Stefan: Known bug in Vcl.Graphics.pas: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21318

Comment: @UweRaabe Did you create PngComponents ?

Comment: @MarusGradinaru: No, I just volunteered to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

I found some libraries like [PNG Delphi](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=6929) and [Delphi PNG and MNG libraries](http://delphi.pjh2.de/articles/graphic/png.php) after Googling.

Comment: Sourceforge no longer hosts PNG Delphi project due copyrasty problems. Download is completely legit.

Answer (score -1):

Although [TPngImage is no longer open source](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2008/08/13/39100), if I take a quick look in an old copy I have lying around here, TPngImage.Assign only checks if the source is a TPngImage, and if not lets the 'default' assign do it's work, and for TBitmap or TGraphic, this will most probably use a plain draw on the canvas which throws away the transparency.

This looks like something to post on [Delphi QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/)

Comment: Hodges was misinforming us on behalf of his employer. Unless your local copyright law enforces a retroactive effect, older releases of PNG Delphi code are still being covered by older license terms which is proprietary and quite restrictive.